# Output for $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex

I have a Mathematica command

```
WriteString[str,TeXForm[ToString[a]^ToString[Divide[p, q]]]]
```

where `a=47`, `p=17` and `q=2`, but the result is $47^{\text{17$\backslash $n--$\backslash $n2}}$

I hope I have $47^{\frac{17}{2}}$.

Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: `TeXForm@HoldForm[47^(17/2)]`?

Comment: Thank you. The command works in Mathematica Notebook, but is not working for the command TeXForm@HoldForm[a^(p/q)]. The result is $\text{a$\$$3208}^{\text{p$\$$3208}/\text{q$\$$3208}}$ for a=47, p=15, q=8

Comment: You should post the code you are using to help reproducing your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should give you the form you want:

`DisplayForm@StyleBox[Superscript[47, Divide[17, 2]], TeXForm]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The command works in notebook, but is not in this command

Comment: fyi, I get "an improperly formatted" message when running your code, windows 7, version 9.01 :  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wkhPV.png)

Answer (score 3):

### Why your output looks like that

You are using `ToString` on subexpressions. As one can read in [`ToString` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToString.html), by default, it converts expressions to strings in `OutputForm`. And in `OutputForm` numerator, fraction bar and denominator are printed in separate lines:

```
In[1]:= ToString[17/2]
        % // FullForm
Out[1]= 17
         --
         2
Out[2]//FullForm=
         "17\n--\n2"
```

### How to get what you want

As @YvesKlett showed in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48937#comment-146351), instead of wrapping subexpressions in `ToString`, you could use `HoldForm` to prevent evaluation.

```
In[3]:= TeXForm@HoldForm[47^Divide[17, 2]]
Out[3]//TeXForm=
         47^{\frac{17}{2}}
```

But `HoldForm` prevents also evaluation of symbols inside it, so even if they have some values set, those values will not be used:

```
In[4]:= a = 47; p = 17 ; q = 2;
         TeXForm@HoldForm[a^Divide[p, q]]
Out[5]//TeXForm=
         a^{\frac{p}{q}}
```

To use values of symbols inside `Hold...` expressions you can assign those values to "local constants" using
[`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html?q=With).
Those constants will be used:

```
In[6]:= With[
             {a = a, p = p, q = q},
             TeXForm@HoldForm[a^Divide[p, q]]
         ]
Out[6]//TeXForm=
         47^{\frac{17}{2}}
```

You could also directly use rules used by Mathematica to replace symbols with their values. You can get them using [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OwnValues.html?q=OwnValues):

```
In[7]:= OwnValues[a]
Out[7]= {HoldPattern[a] :> 47}
```

In your case:

```
In[8]:= TeXForm[HoldForm[a^Divide[p, q]] /. Join[OwnValues[a], OwnValues[p], OwnValues[q]]]
Out[8]//TeXForm=
         47^{\frac{17}{2}}
```